# Using GREP command

Tags: command-line

I have tried to use GREP command but i couldn't figure out exactly how it works. Can someone help be. I want to know how i could use this command to search for the phrase 'Failed password for root' in the auth.log file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all it's `grep` - in lower case.

In general `man grep` will give you an overview of how grep works. For instance, the first paragraph on usage states

> grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
>          grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing  a  match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the matching lines.

PATTERN is what we're looking for, and file is the argument to look trough.

To search for `Failed password for root` in `/var/log/auth.log`, the command would be

```
grep "Failed password for root" /var/log/auth.log
```

The PATTERN has to be quoted, as it contains spaces.

Comment: Note: when PATTERN involves special characters like `*` or `$` that are also recognized by shell, it's better ro use single quotes or at least backslash escapes