# How to scan Terminal output for a string?

Tags: command-line, search

I want to search Terminal output from a command for a string and display only the lines that include that string.

How can I do it?

I'm interested in searching the Terminal output, not a file. I have tried

```
ls --help | grep '--l '
```

but that gave me error.

Comment: Is the output in STDOUT, or already redirected to a file? Or are you asking how to redirect output to a file?

Comment: `command | grep 'string'`

Comment: @user535733: Output is in STDOUT and I want to stay it that way. I want to "filter" only certain lines.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli: ls --help | grep `'-l  '` is giving me error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using GREP command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998433/using-grep-command)

Comment: @ManasSingh: The question is about filtering output of a command, not a file.

Comment: Related: [How to use grep to search through the --help output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164743/how-to-use-grep-to-search-through-the-help-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
command-name | grep 'STRING'
```

If STRING starts with `'-'` or `'--'`, it's necessary to utilize one of the following formats:

```
command-name | grep \\'STRING'
command-name | grep -e 'STRING'
command-name | grep -- 'STRING'
```

Comment: ... or use `-e 'STRING'` to make it explicit that `STRING` is a pattern not an option; or use `--` to signal end of options

Comment: Being more explicit about the last suggestion: `grep -- --l`

Comment: @BlueSkies you can do it, click `edit` at `share edit flag` below your answer.

Comment: They provided the comments so that you could edit and create a complete answer.